# How to see the trace/log in a JellyBean device

Tags: android, logging, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am testing an Android apk in my JellyBean tab (Its a relatively new one in the market, I cant get the drivers and their technical help is also quite useless).

The problem is :

I want to see the log/trace files.

LogCat or any other similar apps can't see the log in Jellybean.

I can't see my tab under adb devices.

The Power + Volume button pressing stops the tab.

Is there any way I can see the log, without rooting the device (I am fairly new to Android, and don't feel very confident doing so)

I can see a “Select debug app” and “Wait for debugger” menu in the tab. Can they be used to debug the application?

Comment: You need to put on developer mode?

Comment: For security reasons it is not possible to access android log files without root access. Google changed that with Jelly Bean. You can put you device in developer mode and view logs using adb.

Comment: The version is 4.1.1, I think the developer mode is from 4.2

Comment: Why was the question down rated?

Comment: Every version got a developers mode, I thought on 4.1.1 it was: Settings -> About Phone -> Then tap 7 times on Buildnumber. Oh and I didn't down-voted btw.

Comment: @Frohnzie...I cant use adb, as I can't see it under devices...

Comment: @Bigflow...I checked the USB Debugging on..if that is what you mean...

Comment: @Bigflow....tapping 7 times I think works from 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can see the log, without rooting the device

No, other than to get and install the ADB driver for your device from the manufacturer.

> The version is 4.1.1, I think the developer mode is from 4.2

The change to `READ_LOGS` was introduced in Android 4.1 IIRC.

Comment: "The change to READ_LOGS"...how to do that?

Comment: @Nandini: `READ_LOGS` is a permission, required for an app to be able to read the logs. As of Android 4.1, apps cannot hold this permission, unless they are part of the firmware.